# send hidden variables through link node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
client.messages.create({
                    to: clientPhoneNumber,
                    from: 'mynumber',
                    body: 'hello ' + clientName + ', your training session begins in 24 hours. To cancel your session anytime within the next 24 hours, click here: http://localhost:3000/cancelevent?eventid=' + eventID + ''
                }, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("err: " + err)
                    }
                    console.log(data)
                });
```

and then it sends then the text message. However, to be honest, it looks ugly for the user. Is it possible to send them the same link but instead hide the `?eventid=' + eventID + ''` part of it? It may be an odd question but thanks for the help!

Comment: In what context, HTML?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' actually no, it is directly from the backend. Sorry I will update to show more relevant code

Comment: So the output goes thru 'console.log'? I'm afraid there's no standard way to format a link in console interface.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' i just updated my q. plz let me know if that is more relevant.

Comment: I see, it's a text message. Sorry, I overlooked this before. Unfortunately, SMS are only plain text, so there's no way to format a hyperlink.

Comment: Only option I see would be a custom URL shortener; to buy a short domain and make redirects, like www.myevent.app/cancel/12345 -> https://www.myfulldomain.org/cancelevent?eventid=12345 or similar

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It really helped me out. I might end up using a url shortened like you said , something like BITLY api.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for anyone in the future that may need this as a reference, I used `tinyurl`

you can install it for `node.js`:

```
npm i tinyurl
```

then what you can do is use it simply like so:

```
    let eventID = "0987654321"
  let url = "http://localhost:3000/cancelevent?eventid=" + eventID + ""
  var TinyURL = require('tinyurl');

    TinyURL.shorten(url).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res)
  }, function(err) {
      console.log(err)
  })
```

and there you have it, simple `url` shortner!